# Is my analysis correct?

Tags: grammar

1. I am quite busy right now, but I can fix/will be able to fix your car on Friday.
2. I don't have any tools I need, but the new ones will arrive in two days. Therefore, I’ll be able to fix your car on Friday.

I think when talking about the available timeslots (schedule) for doing something, we can use either "can" or "will be able to" to refer to future events; on the other hand, if it's talking about future ability (tools, parts, staffers, etc), "will be able to" is better.

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: I don't think that distinction exists. _Can_ is more informal, so _will be able to_ goes better after _therefore_. The mechanic could have said "So I can fix your car on Friday." (NB "I don't have any _of the_ tools I need" would be better.)

Comment: @KateBunting What if it's another verb: "If the tools I need arrive by tomorrow, I can save these kids trapped in the cave on Monday."? I think in this case only "will be able to" is correct instead of "can".